# Ocaml optimised tomorrow function

Tags: ocaml

I am learning Ocaml and as part of an exercise, I have to create a function that returns the following day of a couple (day, month, year).

I did the function, but the software that evaluates my code tells me I'm using too much if ... then ... else ...
I haven't found a solution for several hours. Can someone help me ?

```
let leap = 
  fun x -> 
    x mod 4 = 0 && x mod 100 <> 0 || x mod 400 = 0

let nbDay (month, year) = 
  match month with 
  | 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 8 | 10 | 12 -> 31
  | 4 | 6 | 9 | 11 -> 30
  | 2 -> if leap year then 29 else 28 
  | _ -> 0

let valid (day, month, year) = 
  day <= nbDay (month, year) 
  && day >= 1
  && month<=12 
  && month>= 1 

let tomorrow (day, month, year) = 
  if valid (day, month, year) then 
    if day = nbDay (month, year) then
      if month = 12 then 
        let day = 1 in 
        let month = 1 in 
        let year = year + 1 in 
        (day, month, year)
      else 
        let day = 1 in 
        let month = month + 1 in 
        (day, month, year)
    else 
      let day = day + 1 in  
      (day, month, year)      
  else  
    failwith "invalid date!"
```

Comment: It is hard to answer your question without knowing more about your homework (for which SO isn't really fitted). Do you have a teacher to ask things to?

Comment: my 2 cents : use exception instead of the first if/then/else, may be elsewhere also ; use also modulo and division...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall use `match` more, for example, instead of writing

```
if month = 12 then xxx ...
```

you can write

```
match month with
| 12 -> xxx
...
```

When your condition is more complex, you can use `when`, e.g., instead of writing

```
| 2 -> if is_leap year then x else y
```

you can write

```
| 2 when is_leap year -> x
| 2 -> y
```